# Fetching an Object from a tableview cell using fetchcontroller?

Tags: swift, core-data, fetch

I want the user to be able to click a cell in a table and it retrieve whatever object is at that index path and set it to a variable so i can pull it though to the next VC.

How is this achieved? My logic was to use something like:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "loadTodaysRoutine" { 
      setRoutine = fetchedResultsController.fetchedobjects[indexPath.row]
      if let todaysRoutineController = segue.destination as? RoutineController {
                todaysRoutineController.routineObject = setRoutine
      }
```

I thought that this would make setRoutine the index patch clicked, then i could send it to another VC via a segue, but i feel im missing some steps as it doesnt work!

Thanks for any help filling in the gaps in my understanding

update, whole VC as requested

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class YourWorkoutsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: - DECLARATIONS

    private let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Lift")
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?

    fileprivate var setRoutine: NSManagedObject?

    @IBAction func unwindToTemplates(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
    @IBOutlet weak var workoutTemplateTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var createWorkoutLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: - ACTIONS

    @IBAction func cancelWorkoutSelection(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToRoutineWithSegue", sender: self)
    }

    // MARK: - VIEWDIDLOAD

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
        workoutTemplateTable.delegate = self
        workoutTemplateTable.dataSource = self

        view.backgroundColor = (UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite())

        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (persistentStoreDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to Load Persistent Store")
                print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else {
                self.setupView()

                do {
                    try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
                } catch {
                    let fetchError = error as NSError
                    print("Unable to Perform Fetch Request")
                    print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
                }

                self.updateView()
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - VIEWWILLAPPEAR

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        do {
            try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print("Unable to Perform Fetch Request")
            print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
        }
        self.workoutTemplateTable.reloadData()
    }


    // MARK: - TABLE SETUP

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let userRoutine = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects else { return 0 }
        return userRoutine.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite()
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

        let userRoutine = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = userRoutine.name
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - TABLE UPDATING COMPONENTS

    private func setupView() {
        setupMessageLabel()
        updateView()
    }

    private func setupMessageLabel() {
        createWorkoutLabel.text = "You Don't Have Any Workouts Yet\n Tap + To Create A New Workout"
    }

    fileprivate func updateView() {
        var hasUserRoutines = false
        if let UserRoutine = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects {
            hasUserRoutines = UserRoutine.count > 0
        }
        workoutTemplateTable.isHidden = !hasUserRoutines
        createWorkoutLabel.isHidden = hasUserRoutines

    }

    // MARK: - COREDATA FETCH

    fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserRoutine> = {

        // Create Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserRoutine> = UserRoutine.fetchRequest()
        // Configure Fetch Request
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        // Create Fetched Results Controller
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        return fetchedResultsController
    }()

    // MARK: - ADDING NEW ROUTINE TO THE VC / PUSHING ROUTINE TO TODAYSROUTINE VC

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.setRoutine = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects[indexPath.row]
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "addNewRoutineSegue" {
            if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? WorkoutDesignerController {
                // Configure View Controller
                destinationViewController.managedObjectContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
            }
        }

        if segue.identifier == "loadTodaysRoutine" {

            if let todaysRoutineController = segue.destination as? RoutineController {
                todaysRoutineController.routineObject = self.setRoutine
            }
        }
    }



    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        workoutTemplateTable.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        workoutTemplateTable.endUpdates()
        updateView()
    }

    // MARK: - ADDING TABLE ROW

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch (type) {
        case .insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                workoutTemplateTable.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;
        case .delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                workoutTemplateTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;
        default:
            print("...")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - DELETING TABLE ROW

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            //fetch exercise
            let UserRoutine = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
            //delete exercise
            UserRoutine.delete(fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
            //save exercise persistence
            do {
                try UserRoutine.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: could you post more code?

Comment: such as? this is the segue, i wasnt sure what else is needed to construct a request

Comment: where do you call that segue? (in cellForRowAtIndexPath) ?

Comment: the segue is just linked in the storyboard from the cell prototype

Comment: the tableview is static ?

Answer (score 0):

First create a local `var` in your current `VC` and assign the value to it in your `didSelectRow` like :

```
fileprivate var setRoutine: Any?
.....

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       if let routine = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects[indexPath.row] {
        self.setRoutine = routine
    }
} 

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "loadTodaysRoutine" { 
         if let todaysRoutineController = segue.destination as? RoutineController {
               todaysRoutineController.routineObject = self.setRoutine
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: apparently im not using any didSelectRow method in my superclass to override, what classes does the VC need to be using for this to work? also getting 'Value of optional type '[UserRoutine]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?'

Comment: What is the superclass for your `tableView`? Please refer this doc https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview

Comment: im just using UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate currently

Comment: This `didSelect` method is defined in `UITableViewDelegate`. Please go through the above document, you will understand.

Comment: I assume im missing something but i cant see didselect in the doc above and im using UITableViewDelegate currently but still have the issue

Comment: What issues do you have? and which line it is giving you errors? Could you post whole code in your question?

Comment: well it wasnt part of my question, its your didSelectRowAt function in your answer, it throws method does not override method from its superclass, and then 'Value of optional type '[UserRoutine]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?'

Comment: Please post more code which shows your current `VC` declarations and `fetchedObjects`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130233/discussion-between-santosh-and-infernouk).

Comment: Alright, remove the `override` keyword for `didSelect` method. Now which line the other error you are seeing?

Comment: the line below it, "self.setRoutine = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects[indexPath.row]
" because its pulling up the managedobject but not unwrapping as the error says

Comment: same issue on same row, you arent unwrapping the NSManagedObject pulled from the fetch request

Comment: Then unwrap it, try casting to the right `type`. Do you know what is wrapping/unwrapping?

Comment: pretty sure i can just do "self.setRoutine = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?[indexPath.row]" adding the ? after the fetched object, this solves the error

Comment: out of interest to see if this is working, is there a way to print or check that the object setting sent through has information in it? I tried print(routineObject) but its not doing anything

Comment: Please go to above chat session